# Error: Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts, test skipped

Tags: apex

Error occured in my test file:Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts, test skipped.

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)

public class REST_Upsell_Controller_Test {

    static testMethod void testCreateNewUpsell(){
        Test.startTest();
        string orderId = 'a0555000000N5BnAAK';
        REST_Upsell_Controller.processUpsell('a0555000000N5BnAAK');
        ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c order = [SELECT Id, ChargentOrders__Charge_Amount__c, ChargentOrders__Tax__c, ChargentOrders__Subtotal__c FROM ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c WHERE Id = :orderId];
        order.ChargentOrders__Subtotal__c = 600.66;
            update order;
            System.assertEquals('a0555000000N5BnAAK',order.Id);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a real webservice call during testing. You need to use `WebServiceMock` class to test it.

[This will help I guess.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing.htm)